# New to programming php, and have seen similar problems

Tags: php, arrays, offset, fatal-error, initialization

So currently I'm trying to fix up some old code for a stats server for a game (that is definitely outdated, and has been replaced recently with a new version).  MUCH of the code is deprecated, so it's kind of guesswork on fixing it right, but I found a section thats completely broken that I have no idea how to fix, and it's causing a fatal error.

The code is as follows

```
for ($i=0; $i<$armyCount; $i++)
{
    $summary['total']['time'] += $armies[0]['time'.$i];
    $summary['total']['win'] += $armies[0]['win'.$i];
    $summary['total']['loss'] += $armies[0]['loss'.$i];
    $summary['total']['score'] += $armies[0]['score'.$i];
    $summary['total']['best'] += $armies[0]['best'.$i];
    $summary['total']['worst'] += $armies[0]['worst'.$i];
    $summary['total']['brnd'] += $armies[0]['brnd'.$i];
}
```

The errors I get are as follows

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\dontneedthis\playerstats.inc.php on line 136

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\dontneedthis\playerstats.inc.php on line 136
```

I've seen similar questions asked, and seen how they were resolved, but I don't fully understand how it was done, so don't quite know how to go about fixing this one.  Any assistance would be awesome, and I fully intend to release the bugfixed and fully working code (whenever I get that done) to the community that remains.

Comment: Which one is the line the error message is refering to? And what do `$summary` and `$armies` look like?

Comment: This error message indicates that index 0 of $armies is not set. With your code snipped the source could only be guessed.

Comment: should use : for ($i=0; $i<count($armies); $i++)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your $armies[0]['time'.$i] is initialized as an empty string and not as an array (likely $armies= "").

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

That means that php tries to access your string-variable $armies as an array. If the string is non-empty then this would result in getting single letters from that string. But it seems that $armies is an empty string and so getting the letter with index 0 is not possible.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array
```

means that the result of the operation above (which showed the notice) cannot be accessed as an array. Remember that $armies is a astring and the first letter of the string was accessed and the result of this attempt will be accessed as an array.

Try resolving how the $armies variable is filled and why its filled the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

`$armies` is an empty string, and you are treating it as any array, in an unrecoverable way.

Show us what `$armies` should look like, what you get when you `var_dump($armies);`, and the code from where you assigned it, and we'll help you work out what went wrong.